# why can &Box<ListNode> be assigned to &ListNode?

Tags: rust

I found a variable of type `&Box<ListNode>` can be assigned to a variable of type `&ListNode`. They are different types, I don't known the mechanism behind this. I thought it might because of the `Deref coercion`. But I think `Deref corecion` only occurs in methold solution or parameter passing. I am not sure. Could someone help me? Thanks you very much.

```
 pub struct ListNode {
   pub val: i32,
   pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
 }

 impl ListNode {
   #[inline]
   fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
     ListNode {
       next: None,
       val
     }
   }
 }

fn f1() {
  let node = ListNode::new(0);
  let mut ref_node:&ListNode = &node;
  let mut ref_box :&Box<ListNode>= &Box::new(ListNode::new(10));

  // why &Box<ListNode> can be assign to &ListNode?
  ref_node = ref_box; 
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-AsRef%3CT%3E

Comment: @MartinGallagher Thanks for you reply. There is no explict calling `as_ref()` here, is there an implicit calling as_ref() when assignment occurs? I found there is `impl AsRef<Path> for str`, I checked  and found a variable of &str cannot be assigned to a variable of &Path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this is because of [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion). Coercions can be done at any [coercion site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites) which includes *"`let` statements where an explicit type is given"*.